# How to remove special characters from rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in pandas data frame like the one shown below;

```
LGA

Alpine (S)
Ararat (RC)
Ballarat (C)
Banyule (C)
Bass Coast (S)
Baw Baw (S)
Bayside (C)
Benalla (RC)
Boroondara (C)
```

What I want to do, is to remove all the special characters from the ending of each row. ie. (S), (RC).

Desired output should be;

LGA

```
Alpine
Ararat
Ballarat
Banyule
Bass Coast
Baw Baw
Bayside
Benalla
Boroondara
```

I am not quite sure how to get desired output mentioned above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have different approach using regex. It will delete anything between brackets:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = {'LGA': ['Alpine (S)', 'Ararat (RC)', 'Bass Coast (S)']  }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['LGA'] = [re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", x).strip() for x in df['LGA']] # delete anything between brackets
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'LGA': ['Alpine (S)', 'Ararat (RC)', 'Bass Coast (S)']  }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df[['LGA','throw away']] = df['LGA'].str.split('(',expand=True)
```

Comment: if it always between  ( ) , use ( as delimiter to split column.

Comment: comment on Sibtain Reza code. just have to change x.split() to x.split('(')

Comment: wont work on "Bass Coast". Change code to  df['LGA'] = df['LGA'].apply(lambda x : x.split('(')[0])

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pandas` str.replace

```py
…
dataf['LGA'] = dataf['LGA'].str.replace(r"\([^()]*\)", "", regex=True)
```

#### Demo

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.DataFrame({
"LGA":\
"""Alpine (S)
Ararat (RC)
Ballarat (C)
Banyule (C)
Bass Coast (S)
Baw Baw (S)
Bayside (C)
Benalla (RC)
Boroondara (C)""".split("\n")
})

output = dataf['LGA'].str.replace(r"\([^()]*\)", "", regex=True)

print(output)
```

```sh
0        Alpine 
1        Ararat 
2      Ballarat 
3       Banyule 
4    Bass Coast 
5       Baw Baw 
6       Bayside 
7       Benalla 
8    Boroondara 
Name: LGA, dtype: object
```